# How to gzip a directory, transfer via scp, and decompress in one command?

Tags: command-line, rsync, scp, gzip

I frequently transfer large directories over `scp` and it would be sweet if I could somehow compress the directory, send it, and decompress it all in one.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about using `rsync` instead with the `-z` option enabled for compression?

```
rsync -az --progress source_dir/* remote_host:/destination_dir
```

This also has the added benefit that if the file already exists and has not changed on the destination, it will not be transferred.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @johnshen64's answer, I was able to come up with something quite nice

```
tar -zc path/to/source | ssh user@remote tar -zxC path/to/destination
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't show progress as it transfers. I have noticed incredible speed improvements using this method.

If anyone know how to show progress for a transfer like this, I'd greatly appreciate the help :)

Comment: Insert [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) between *tar* and *ssh*.

Comment: This is great if you don't have rsync available

Answer (score 2):

well, i would use tar instead

tar cf - directory | ssh server 'tar xf -'

you can add v to verify.

zip should be the same, but tar is more robust for linux in my opinion.

Comment: +1 thanks for your help; this got me half way there. I was able to come up with a solution that doesn't use the cryptic `-` character, also uses gzip compression and allows to target a destination directory.

Comment: @macek: Note that `f -` might be required on other operating systems, since most *tar* versions will try to read from a tape drive otherwise. Reading from stdin by default is GNU-specific.